# Генерация PHP файлов с данными из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Привет! Есть большая база данных с несколькими десятками тысяч записей. Возникла необходимость на основе этих данных из SQL сгенерировать PHP файлы, чтобы после того как пользователь ввел данные, его бы перекидывало сразу на нужный файл, без использования MySQL. В общем, нужно перенести данные с MySQL базы в PHP файлы. А там же в процессе генерация скриптом, вставлять include чтобы в будущем натянуть дизайн. Таблица простая, четыре столбца и все. Подскажите?

Comment: А то же самое, но как-то понятней, можно? Какие PHP-файлы нужно генерировать, что должно быть в них? Что должен увидеть пользователь после "перекидывания", дамп базы со своими данными, что ли?

Comment: База например такая:
Col1   Col2   Col3<br/>
Angel  Love   Me

В результате PHP файл примерно такой:
include файл с style.css<br/>
Angel Love Me - вторая строчка

Файл назвать AngelLove. Если пользователь ввел в форму поиска "AngelLove", то его перекидывает на site.com/AngelLove.php.
Вот вроде бы и все. Но да Бог с этим редиректом, сейчас бы с генерацией разобраться. А там уже проще будет.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такое решение на сквозном (ленивом) кэше. В качестве простейшего варианта кэша - файлы.

```
<?php
/**
 * пример: вставка таблицы с использованием кэша
 */
require_once('Cache.php'); // загрузить описание класса кэша
$cache = new Cache;
$tableName = 'моя таблица';
$tableHTML = $cache->get($tableName);
if (false === $tableHTML) // в кэше не нашлось
{
    $rows = array( // тут надо выбрать из базы данных строки $rows
        array('Col1' => 'Angel', 'Col2' => 'Love', 'Col3' => 'Me'),
        // и другие строки
    );
    ob_start(); // открыть буфер
    include('table.php'); // внутри файла переменная $rows будет видна как локальная переменная
    $tableHTML = ob_get_clean(); // извлечь буфер и закрыть его
    $cache->set($tableName, $tableHTML, 3600); // поместить таблицу в кэше на 3600 секунд = 1 час
}

// и вот наконец то...
echo $tableHTML; // показываем таблицу на странице
```

---

Файл table.php, который генерирует таблицу в формате HTML

```
<?php
/**
 *  файл table.php
 *  отрисовка таблицы
 * @var array $rows
 */
?>
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($rows as $row) { // example $row = array('Col1' => 'a', 'Col2' => 'b', 'Col3' => 'c'
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['Col1'] ?>
            <td><?php echo $row['Col2'] ?>
            <td><?php echo $row['Col3'] ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody></table>
```

---

Файл Cache.php, в котором дан простейший класс для хранения данных в кэше

```
<?php
/**
 * файл Cache.php
 * Класс для хранения данные в кэше
 * 
 * Реализация на файлах, но можно использовать ещё много разных реализаций: memcache, memcached, mongo, redis, ...
 */
class Cache {

    public $path = '/path/to/cache';

    public function __construct()
    {
        // инициализация кэша
        if (!is_dir($this->path)) // если директория для кэша не существует ...
            mkdir($this->path, true, 0755); // создать директорию
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает данные из кэша
     * @param $key ключ в кэше
     * @return bool|mixed
     */
    public function get($key)
    {
        $filePath = $this->path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5($key); // имя файла в кэшэ как функция от ключа
        if (!is_file($filePath) || !is_readable($filePath)) // если файла нет или нельзя прочитать, значит и данных нет
            return false;
        $contentJSON = file_get_contents($filePath); // прочитать файл
        list($expired, $content) = json_decode($contentJSON); // разбить на дату устаревания и собственно данные
        if ($expired > time()) // если дата устаревания меньше текущего времени
            return false; // забыть про данные
        return $content;
    }

    /**
     * Сохраняет данные в кэше
     * @param $key ключ в кэше
     * @param $content данные
     * @param $lifetime время жизни данных в кэше в секундах
     * @return bool
     */
    public function set($key, $content, $lifetime)
    {
        $filePath = $this->path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5($key); // имя файла в кэшэ как функция от ключа
        if (!is_writable($filePath)) // если файл нельзя записать, значит пытаться не стоит
            return false;
        $expired = time() + $lifetime; // время устаревания
        $contentJSON = json_encode(array($expired, $content)); // упаковать время устаревания и контент в JSON
        file_put_contents($filePath, $contentJSON);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: >>> Если пользователь ввел в форму поиска "AngelLove"

Тебе надо ключ указывать с этим словом `$tableName = 'моя таблица для слова AngelLove';`

Тогда для разных слов данные в кэше будут в разных ключах, то есть файлах